# 2-in-1 convertible with numpad, 8 threads and discrete graphics card

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, keyboards

I have been looking for a long while now but every product I found had something missing. It's like manufacturers make a product, fix some issues in the next iteration but make something worse; every time.

Here is a list of what I would really like to have:

- 8 threads CPU (which means either 4 core w/ HT or 8 core, thanks to Intel quad-core CPUs are practically non-existent nowadays)
- 2-in-1, 360° variant seems the most available but others like detachable are OK as well
- Discrete GPU, GTX 1050 4GB (or equivalent) is what I am heading for
- Numpad, seems like an optional nowadays, the numpad automatically requires a minimal screen size of 15"

  - Sidenote: 15" or bigger laptops w/out numpad are just stupid (damn you Yoga 420 15")
- Ethernet Port
- 2 USB 3.0 Ports
- A headphone jack
- At least one USB C port
- DisplayPort (preferably) or HDMI
- Rotation sensor
- Mousepad with dedicated mouse keys

  - Two-finger scrolling and pinch support
- Fingerprint reader
- 1080p or similar resolution screen, would actually prefer 16:10 aspect ratio (like I'd have no problem with a 1600x1000 screen)

  - IPS
- No weird keyboards, standard layout a.k.a. now space saving hacks like half sized arrow keys

Nice to have but not super important:

- Dedicated media keys
- NVMe SSD 250GB
- 100% sRGB coverage and good colours
- Build in HSDPA+ or LTE modem

Cool optional:

- A touch bar like the one in the MacBook Pro something 2017? (not gonna comment here)

I know It's a lot but some help would be appreciated. Thank You!

I'd love if a manufacturer would read this and reach out to me to beta test a possible new laptop?

P.S.: If something comes to my mind I'll update the post and mark any changes.

Comment: The [Lenovo Yoga 720 (15")](http://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/yoga/700-series/Yoga-720-15/p/88YG7000828) looks close, but violats a few of your mandatory features. It has half-sized up-down arrows AFAICT, it has no HDMI / DP port AFAICT, it has no Ethernet AFAICT, it has no dedicated numpad AFAICT and the 1050 only has 2GB of VRAM. But everything else it has and the missing features you _could_ work-around (USB <-> Ethernet connector, Miracast or TB3 <-> HDMI and an external keyboard, maybe even eGPU). I don't post this as an answer because of the violated mandatory requirements.

Comment: Thank you @SEJPM, yes it seems like the best option out there.. Sadly I need a new laptop ASAP as my current one broke. I'll probably go with that one as something I'm looking for probably will never come out. Thank you very much! #Dongles4Life I guess..